# Is there a divine law in Hinduism?

Tags: vedas, upanishads

The vedas are the scripture of authority the highest. So do the vedas has a law or constitution that every one must follow to achieve salvation(Moksha) . Please give reference from **vedas and upanishad** only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a divine law in Hinduism?

That divine law is called karma. Various verses in the Upanishads declare the fruits of various good and bad actions. For example:

> Chhandogya Upanishad 5.10.7 - Those whose **conduct has been good** here
> will shortly get birth such as a brahmana, a kshatriya, or a vaishya.
> But those whose conduct has been evil will be born in evil births
> shortly such as the birth of a dog, or as a pig, or a chandala.

Then there are also references to the path of moksha:

> Isha Upanishad verse 3 - There are the worlds of the Asuras covered
> by blind darkness. Those who have destroyed their self (who perform
> works, without having arrived at a knowledge of the true Self ), go
> to those worlds after death.
>
> Chhandogya Upanishad [last verse](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe01/sbe01175.htm) - ... he who behaves thus all his
> life, reaches the world of Brahman, and does not return, truly, he does
> not return.

> Kaushitaki Upanishad - For he Brahman makes him, the Jivatma, whom he wishes to lead up from these worlds, do a good deed; and he also makes him, whom he wishes to lead down from these worlds, do a bad deed.

So there is definitely a divine law in Hinduism. The divine law governs which births one takes based on good and bad actions, as well as the path to moksha.